# Domain Object and DAO. How to do queries from within the Domain Object but still having both objects not know each other exists

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, datamapper, dao

Ok so I have my DomainObject/Model called `$user` and my `$userDAO` object.

From what I have read so far when I need to do a CRUD operation like fetch a `$user` object I just do:

```
$user = $userDAO->fetchById($userId);
```

and that will return my `$user` object.

Apparently the DomainObject is not supposed to know that the DAO object exists and vice versa but what if the user is registering and I run the `$user->register()` method

```
$user->register($firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress, $username, $password etc.);
```

Somewhere in that method I need to check if the chosen username has already been taken and the same with the email address.

The only way I can think of doing this is having an instance of the `$userDAO` object in my `$user` object and then doing the validation like:

```
if($this->userDAO->isUsernameTaken($username)) {
    // the username is already in use
}
else {
    // continue on
}
```

But that would break the rule that the DomainObject should not know about the database stuff and vice versa but I was thinking the DomainObject doesn't really know about the database stuff because all the queries are in the DAO object, it just holds a reference to an object but it does not explicitly know what goes on in that object. Am I right or wrong?

If I'm doing it the wrong way how am I supposed to run a method like `$user->register()` which needs to call some database queries inside of it which needs access to a data source but the DomainObject/Model is not allowed know about any data source so the experts say?

I've gone onto page numbers on Google today I thought I'd never have to go onto and I still can't find any very solid real life examples of what to do and I'm starting to go mad because it's slowling down everything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of the architecture of your application in terms of a layered architecture, you need to build another layer on top of Domain Layer and DAO layer, leaving these two layers the way they are. This new layer is called service layer, or application layer by some. The job of this service layer is to perform use cases, such as "registering" a new user. For example, one class in service layer may be UserService which peforms use cases related to user,

```
class UserService {

private UserDao userDao;

// constructor
userSercie(){

}

// registers a user
register($firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress, $username, $password etc.) {
    $user = $userDAO->fetchByName($username);
    if($user != null) {
         // the username is already in use
    }
    else {
       // continue on
    }

   }

 // other service methods such as


}
```

Why do we need service layer? It is exactly in response to problems like yours, that we need service layer. This way you can see that we can keep separation of concerns between different module.

Comment: Ah yes that's what I was missing thanks. One thing though, the `$fetchByName()` method will return a `$user` object if it finds a row in the database with that username? And if I want to check if the supplied email address already exists I have use my `$fetchByEmail()` method?

Comment: I used the name fetchByName, which is typically a method in CRUD, besides fetchById. But, in any case, that was a example to show my point about what service methods look and behave like. Of course, you can have more DAO methods such as fetchByEmail() etc. But, in general,  something like userDAO->isUsernameTaken($username) is not right, performing this check is not responsiblity of DAO, it should be done in the service layer, using DAO, as I already showed.

Comment: Ok thanks but then instead of just being able to do `userDAO->isUsernameTaken($username)` which executes one small simple query returning a boolean the correct thing to do is `$user = $userDAO->fetchByName($username);` and that will create a User object if a row was returned so then I check if the username exists by doing `if($user != null)`? It just seems really inefficient and overkill to me. When I start doing it this way I can already see I'm going to  have to be making functions returning objects all the time instead of just booleans.

Comment: You realize that the check is not thread safe right? It would probably be better to catch a unique db constraint exception.